# "None of the customers were happy, _______?" What will the question tag be in this sentence?

Tags: verb-agreement, questions

My English teacher says it will be "None of the customers were happy, *weren't they?*" I know this is wrong, and it should be *were they*, but my teacher won't listen to me, so I just want to clarify here.

Comment: You are right. "None of the customers were happy" is negative, so the tag should be the positive "were they?". Note that most constructions of this nature have a reversed polarity tag.

Comment: @BillJ Since you know the answer, please write it in the answer box.

Comment: @BillJ please post your response as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *None of the customers were happy, ____ they?*

You are right.

"None of the customers were happy" is a negative clause , so the tag should be the positive "were they?"

Note that most constructions of this nature have a reversed polarity tag. Your example is no exception.